# What should I change in my code to set 5 ZIP code digits instead of 6?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

So this is my code which I've written with help from others because I don't understand that validating concept very well.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.bootstrapValidator.validators.usZipCode = {
        /**
         * Return true if and only if the input value is a valid US zip code
         *
         * @param {BootstrapValidator} validator The validator plugin instance
         * @param {jQuery} $field Field element
         * @param {Object} options
         * @returns {boolean}
         */
        validate: function(validateInstance, $field, options) {
            var value = $field.val();
            return /^\d{5}([\-]\d{4})?$/.test(value);
        }
    };
}(window.jQuery));
```

Comment: Your form is already validating a US zip code, which is always at least 5 digits, and sometimes zip+4. What exact format do you want to validate?

Comment: Please provide sample data, the current result, and the desired result if the above is not producing what you want/expect it to.

Comment: When I enter 5 digit code, it says "Enter a valid pin code" and when I add one more digit then it's fine. That means that, somehow, validation is set up to 6 digits.

Comment: @Tamara  Can you create a runnable snippet here that demonstrates that?

Comment: @Tamara  Also, why are you applying this to a "pin code" field?  Are you sure that you're not looking at the wrong thing?